# Grpc requiring glibc 2.33 debian buster on arm cpu

Tags: python, python-3.x, glibc

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steven/GassistPi/src/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    from google.cloud import speech
  File "/home/steven/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/speech.py", line 19, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech_v1 import SpeechClient
  File "/home/steven/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech_v1.gapic import speech_client
  File "/home/steven/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/speech_client.py", line 22, in <module>
    import google.api_core.gapic_v1.client_info
  File "/home/steven/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
  File "/home/steven/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/config.py", line 23, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/home/steven/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc import _compression
  File "/home/steven/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/steven/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

I am trying to setup this project GassistPi but I am getting the error above when I run the main python script.

The default version that came with debian buster is 2.28. I am running this in a python virtual envirorment. Is there a way I can tell the python virtual enviroment to use the glibc I have compiled and installed in a different folder?

I have tested the glibc install by running the testrun script againest my hello world c program. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can tell the python virtual enviroment to use the glibc I have compiled and installed in a different folder?

No. Detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).